# is room temperature quantum (qubit) nuclear magnetic resonance possible?

Tags: quantum-information, radio-frequency, precession, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

I know it is possible to do room temperature NMR. Not just that but one can also use the earth's magnetic field for the nuclei to precess about. If done this way, one gets precession at about the KHz range. The reason being that with such a weak magnetic field, there is not much Larmor "force" to oscillate the nuclei.

I was wondering if it is possible to do any 1-2 qubit algorithms in this type of environment. Supposedly 2 qubit decoherence for molecules like chloroform-13 takes place in the millisecond range. This makes me think that there might be enough time to get qubit results for at least some of the population in my c-13 sample before it decoheres.

Am I thinking about this correctly? Is there another factor which limits ones ability to do room temperature QNMR?